# npm install mongodb fails (seems node-gyp related)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, beagleboneblack, node-gyp

I have a Node.JS webserver hosted on my BeagleBone Black at home and I'd like to interface it with mongodb, so the natural thing to do was `npm install mongodb`.

Obviously, it didn't work. I've googled it but didn't find my solution.

Here's (part of) what the command outputs :

```
make: *** [Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o] Error 1                                                                     
make: Leaving directory `/home/fointard/NodeJs/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'                                                      
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.8.13-bone72
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/fointard/NodeJs/node_modules/utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v5.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate Exit status 1

npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/fointard/NodeJs/package.json'
npm WARN EPEERINVALID mongodb-core@1.2.26 requires a peer of kerberos@~0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON /home/fointard/NodeJs No description
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON /home/fointard/NodeJs No repository field.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON /home/fointard/NodeJs No README data
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON /home/fointard/NodeJs No license field.
```

It seems like node-gyp fails to build some dependencies.

```
uname -a
```

gives

```
Linux haystack 3.8.13-bone72 #1 SMP Tue Jun 16 21:36:04 UTC 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

and

```
lsb_release -da
```

gives

```
Distributor ID: Debian                                                                                                                 
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.9 (wheezy)                                                                                          
Release:        7.9                                                                                                                    
Codename:       wheezy
```

Anyone having insights to share ? It'd be very welcome !

EDIT : I solved the problem. Seems like the issue was caused by my C++ compiler (G++ 4.6.x) which did not support C++11.

1. Upgrade from Debian Wheezy to Jessie (7.x to 8.x)
2. GCC 4.9.2 was already installed, it supports C++11 whereas my old 4.6.x version did not
3. `sudo apt-get install libkrb5-dev` : required to build node.js kerberos module
4. `npm install kerberos` : manual install is required as npm v3.x+ doesn't install it by itself
5. `npm install mongodb` : done

Fointard

Comment: Which version of node are you using? Try rolling back to v4 or even to v0.1x using `nvm` and see how that goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. Seems like the issue was caused by my C++ compiler (G++ 4.6.x) which did not support C++11.

1. Upgrade from Debian Wheezy to Jessie (7.x to 8.x)
2. GCC 4.9.2 was already installed, it supports C++11 whereas my old 4.6.x version did not
3. `sudo apt-get install libkrb5-dev` : required to build node.js kerberos module
4. `npm install kerberos` : manual install is required as npm v3.x+ doesn't install it by itself
5. `npm install mongodb` : done

Fointard

Answer (score 1):

Are you by any chance running a version of node below v0.12? I tried installing the `utf-8-validate` package with v0.11.x, v.0.12.x, v.4.x and v.5.x and it succeeded on all of them except v0.11.x, so that might be where your problem is. Use [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install a different version of node and try again!

Comment: `node -v` gives `v5.0.0` as shown in my original post, I don't think this is the issue here. Node-gyp seems up to date too...